# etiqueta SELECT HTML

Tags: php, html

Disculpen lo que pasa es que soy nuevo en programación con php y tengo una duda, al momento de validar una etiqueta SELECT con php, lo que deseo que haga es que el usuario al momento de darle clic a una opción el correo al que se enviará por defecto cambie dependiendo la opción que elija el usuario, necesito a fuerzas javascript o con php solo mando a llamar la opción? este es mi código html:

```
<form method="POST" action="contact.php" id="formulario" onSubmit="alert('Gracias por contactarnos, Nos comunicaremos contigo a la brevedad!');">
            <div class="form">
                <h2 class="formulario-letras text-center"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> Déjanos tu mensaje</h2>
                <h4 class="opciones-letras text-center">¿Qué desea hacer?</h4>
                <select name="opciones" id="opciones">
                    <option value="0" selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
                    <option value="1">Comentarios</option>
                    <option value="2" >Solicitar factura</option>
                </select>
```

y este mi código php

```
<?php 

 $nombre= isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
 $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
 $telefono = isset($_POST['telefono']) ? $_POST['telefono'] : '';
 $asunto = isset($_POST['asunto']) ? $_POST['asunto'] : '';
 $mensaje = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : '';
 $contenido = '    

                    <html>
                        <head>          
                        </head>
                    <body>
                        <h2>Haz recibido un mensaje a través de la página</h2>
                        <p>'. $nombre .' te ha enviado el siguiente mensaje:</p>
                        <p>'. $mensaje .'<br><br> Puedes ponerte en contacto con la persona al email: '. $email .'</p>
                        <p>o al telefono: '. $telefono .'</p>
                        <hr>
                    </body>
                    </html>';


  //configuración de los encabezados

   $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

   //Enviar correo
   $envio=mail('dirección1@hotmail.com' ,$asunto, $contenido, 
   $headers);
   $envio2=mail('direccion2@hotmail.com', $asunto, $contenido, $headers);

   //Reseteo
   $msg = $tuSeleccion = NULL;

 //validar opciones
 if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){
 //selección obligatoria

if(empty($_POST['opciones'] [0])){
    $msg = 'Debes elegir una opción';
}

else{
    //obtenemos el dato del option seleccionado
    $tuSeleccion= $_POST['opciones'];
}



//Verdadero seleción

if(isset($_POST['opciones'] [1]))
{
    echo "yes";
}

else if(isset($_POST['opciones'] [2]))
{
    echo "no";
}
}
```

Ayuda porfavor es para un proyecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El valor regresado en `$_POST["opciones"]` contiene el valor seleccionado por el susuario, no tienes que validar todos. vasta con usar ese valor para decidir a que email mandar en tu php:

```
$opciones = $_POST['opciones'];
switch($opciones){
    case "0": email = "opcion0@company.com";
    break;
    case "1": email = "opcion1@company.com";
    break;
    case "2": email = "opcion2@company.com";
    break;
    default: email = "default@company.com";
}
```

Comment: Graciasss por tu ayuda